# Why does grequests.get() return None?

Tags: python, web-scraping, grequests

I'm trying to fetch automatically the MAC addresses for some vendors in Python. I found [a website](https://aruljohn.com/mac/000000) that is really helpful, but I'm not being able to access its information from Python. When I run this:

```
import grequests

rs = (grequests.get(u) for u in ['https://aruljohn.com/mac/000000'])
requests = grequests.map(rs)
for response in requests:
    print(response)
```

It prints `None`. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: per the [docs](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) it looks like this is what happens when you pass it an invalid url

Comment: @C.Nivs The URL works just fine.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like the issue is just not setting a `user-agent` in the `headers`. I was able to `request` the website without any issues. I just used normal `python request` but it should work fine with `grequests`. I do think you might want to find a more active library. You could check out `aiohttp`. Very active and I have had a wonderful experience using `aiohttp`.

```
import requests

from lxml import html

def request_website(mac):
    url = 'https://aruljohn.com/mac/' + mac

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
    }
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return r.text

response = request_website('000000')
tree = html.fromstring(response)
results = tree.cssselect('.results p')[0].text
print (results)
```